# Playing with Nat without case classes

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, unapply

I just create a definition in scala for Naturals, and also a PLUS operation:

```
abstract class Nat {

  def +(other:Nat):Nat = this match {
    case Zero => other
    case Succ(x) => x + Succ(other)
  }

}

object Zero extends Nat {
  override def toString = "Zero"
}
```

And for the definition of Succ, i tryit not to use a Case class, for learning purposes. My first approach was:

```
class Succ(x: Nat) extends Nat {
  override def toString = "Succ(" + x.toString + ")"
}

object Succ {
  def apply(x: Nat) = new Succ(x)

  def unapply(s: Succ) = Some(s.x)
}
```

But the compiler throws me an error

```
Error:(  , ) value x is not a member of Succ
  def unapply(s: Succ) = Some(s.x)
                              ^
```

I make an explicit method for get X, and it works

```
class Succ(x: Nat) extends Nat {

  def getX = x

  override def toString = "Succ(" + x.toString + ")"
}

object Succ {
  def apply(x: Nat) = new Succ(x)

  def unapply(s: Succ) = Some(s.getX)

}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor arguments are only visible inside the class. If you want to make it a field, you'll have to say so:

```
class Succ(val x: Nat) extends Nat { … }
//         ^^^
```